# Transparency using WS_EX_TRANSPARENT on 16-bit color depth

Tags: c#, wpf, transparency

I have a WPF application which does annotations on the computer screen, by painting on a transparent window. Transparency is set using PInvoke :

```
extendedWindowStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedWindowStyle | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
```

Now I have problems when I turn down the display adapter colordepth from 32-bit to 16-bit.
At that moment I am no longer able to paint on the transparent window, instead the mouse reaches the control below the transparent WPF window. Any ideas how to solve this ?

(BTW using PInvoke was the only way I got transparency working correctly on "Windows Basic" and "High contrast" themes which turn off Aero transparency)

Comment: WS_EX_TRANSPARENT is a pretty weak Windows hack to emulate transparency, appropriate only for child windows.  One that a WPF app should never need, very unclear why you are using it.  A top-level window should use AllowTransparency = True with a 0% opaque background brush.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out the problem had nothing to do with setting transparency through WS_EX_TRANSPARENT or through AllowTransparency=true in WPF, it had to do with the "0% opaque background brush". I simply overlooked what I had done there: in order to paint on a transparent canvas, you cannot set it 0% opaque, because that causes your mouse events to be ignored. Therefore I set opacity to 01 (Background="#01FFFFFF"). Now I realize that this value is too small to be detected when using a 16-bit color resolution. It is seen as 0% opacity and mouse events are no longer captured. Setting the background to "04FFFFFF" solved the problem. Just in case someone else hits the same problem - I was just looking at the wrong part of the code trying to solve this...